# Getting error "System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute from assembly 'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0'"

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mscorlib

I am new to C#, need help in debugging an error, nothing much on internet was helpful.

I Changed *Target Framework* from .net 2 to .net 4 for related projects, after this I started getting this error.

**The error is:**

> ''System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

I found that this *TargetFrameworkAttribute* is not available in *mscorlib* *2.0.0.0* but available in *mscorlib* *4.0.0.0*, but don't know from where it is picking mscorlib of version 2.0.0.0 .

I **found the code** which is causing problem, but now don't know what to look for here.

> this.inCallWaitPictureBox.Image =
>   ((System.Drawing.Image)resources.GetObject("inCallWaitPictureBox.Image")));

*System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources
System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox PresetupForm.inCallWaitPictureBox*

I also found that this func ***GetObject***() is in ***mscorlib*** assembly.

plz give me some pointers to resolve this error.

Comment: Iirc you get this error if you reference a 4.0 assembly from a 2.0 assembly. I'd check all my references again, preferably even remove them all (from the bin folder) and make sure they aren't in the project anymore. There was also a way to check the assembly version from a DLL, but can't remember it; Google will give you that answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
I solved the same problem switching "<NoStdLib>true</NoStdLib>" with "<NoStdLib>false</NoStdLib>" into my_project.csproj file
```